# PDFTK: unable to open file for output

Tags: permissions, tmp

I am making use of PDFTK to watermark PDF files using the following command:

```
pdftk /tmp/55180af7c8c88.pdf stamp /tmp/stamp55180af7c95b84.58412952.pdf output /tmp/55180af7c95c81.06110501.pdf
```

However the above results in:

```
Error: Failed to open output file:
   /tmp/55180af7c95c81.06110501.pdf
   No output created.
Error: unable to open file for output: /tmp/55180af7c95c81.06110501.pdf
```

The above is a strange error because PDFTK should be creating that output file!

If I put `sudo` infront of the command, no error is thrown. But I am writing to the tmp folder and this is writeable by all I thought?

I am running PDFTK from PHP's `exec` command. To be 100% sure that this isn't a permissions issue, I made the `/tmp` folder owner and group to be `www-data`, which is the apache user but the same error is thrown.

I now have no idea what is going on, I appreciate any help!

Comment: What is output of this command, please, `ls -ld /tmp /tmp/55180af7c95c81.06110501.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

You should not be fiddling around with the permissions for `/tmp`. It's an important part of the system. I suspect that the reason your `pdftk` command is failing is because `/tmp` is incorrectly set up. To restore the permissions on `tmp` run the following commands as root:

```
chown root:root /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

The result will leave the permissions and owner/group of `/tmp` looking like this:

```
ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 12288 Mar 29 18:05 /tmp
```

Based on further investigation, I suspect that now we have got `/tmp` sorted out, the reason that the `pdftk` is failing is that the output file already exists but is not writeable by the application. *(Awaiting update via comments.)*

Comment: This was the state of permissions in the first place. I have changed it back. But this doesn't solve the initial problem.

Comment: Maybe not, but at least `/tmp` is now in a sane state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got selinux enabled? Have a look at [this previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448519/execution-of-pdftk-from-php-script-is-failing-with-error-code-11), please.

I am editing this after your kind comment about SELinux/AppArmor not being relevant. If I were you, *and this a long shot*, I would take a look at the filesystem you are using for /tmp. If it is not tmpfs and it is get close to be full, you may experience issues similar to the one you describe. As you are probably aware of, once a filesystem gets close to be full, it only allows root to write on it.

Again, hope it helps!

Comment: I used `sestatus` to check if is selniux is enabled but it is disabled. In addition, `apparmor` is enabled but it's just the basic setup and it isn't blocking pdftk as it isn't in any of the profiles.